# What is the value of this expression

Tags: logarithms

> If $ \log_p q + \log_q r + \log_r p = 0  $
>
> Then what is the value of,
>
> $$(\log_p q)^3 + (\log_q r)^3 + (\log_r p)^3$$
>
> given that $p,q,r \neq 1$
>
> A. It is odd prime
>
> B. It is even prime
>
> C. Odd composite
>
> D. Irrational

I have tried using the identity that, if $ a + b + c = 0$, $a^3+b^3+c^3= 3abc$ , but it gives me the answer $0$.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: What is $abc$ here?

Comment: Your method is right but how did you get $abc=0$?

Comment: $ log_p q = a, log_q r =b, log_r p=c $

Comment: Maybe my further steps are wrong

Comment: It is 3.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$ when $x+y+z=0$.

AND

$\log_p q=\frac{\log q}{\log p}$, $\log_q r=\frac{\log r}{\log q}$, $\log_r p=\frac{\log p}{\log r}$.

Comment: I'm trying it out.

Comment: Oh Yes! I got 3  which is odd prime. Thanks a lot for second hint.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the identity

$$a+b+c=0 \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+c^3 =3abc,$$ the answer is 3. Just note that

$\log_p(q)=\frac{ln(q)}{ln(p)},$ etc, so your hypothesis is just

$$\frac{ln(q)}{ln(p)}+\frac{ln(r)}{ln(q)}+\frac{ln(p)}{ln(r)}=0.$$ Put now

$$a= \frac{ln(q)}{ln(p)} , \; b=\frac{ln(r)}{ln(q)},\; c=\frac{ln(p)}{ln(r)}$$ and note that $abc=1.$

Hope this helps